# jQuery dynamically and proportionally resize fonts

Tags: jquery, css, font-size

I'd like to have jQuery resize fonts on the page but do so proportionally to all elements with  certain class assigned (.resizeFont). Let's say I want the size to double.

css linked to main html:

```
#titleText {
    font-size:50px;
}
#mainText {
    font-size:20px;
}
#footnoteText {
    font-size:8px;
}
```

main html:

```
<div id='#titleText'></div>
<div id='#mainText'></div>
<div id='#footnoteText'></div>
```

in external html files (each line in separate file):

```
<p class='someClass'>some text</p> // title.html

<p class='resizeFont'>some text</p> // main.html

<p class='resizeFont'>some text</p> // footnote.html
```

After jQuery is done with it, both #mainText and #footnoteText should have font sizes of 40px and 16px respectivly but #titleText should retain 50px size

what's the approach here, do I have to get jQuery to build an array of all elements with .resizeFont assigned and process that through math multiplier?

...I'm loading the text through ajax, not sure if that influences how properties of the font are read/written

```
$.ajax({
   success : function (data) {
        $('#titleText').load('title.html');
        $('#mainText').load('main.html');
        $('#footnoteText').load('footnote.html');
   },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `font-size` property in some `percent` value, just like,

```
table{ font-size:50% }
```

Using `jQuery` you can do it like,

```
$('table').css('font-size', '100%')
```

Or

```
$('table').css('font-size', '70%')
```

Or individually for a `td`

```
$("td.tablecol_0").animate({ 
    'width' : (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
    'minWidth' : (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
    'maxWidth' : (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
    'fontSize' : (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + '%'
}, 1000);
```

If you set `100%` for all `tds` then you can simply use `$(`table`).css('fontSize', '100%')`.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2xx6F/3/)

http://jsfiddle.net/2xx6F/3/